# How to compensate for overcount?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Task:** Find the number of ways to distribute 10 customers (distinguishable) to 7 salesmen (dist.) with each having at least 1 customer.

**Attempt**: We first pick 7 customers (unordered: $C(10,7)$) and give 1 to each salesman (order matters thus $P(7,7)$ ways to do this) for a total of $C(10,7) \cdot P(7,7) = P(10,7) $ ways. We now have 7 options for the remaining 3 customers, thus we get $P(10,7) \cdot 7^3$ total. However, whenever a salesman has more than 1 customer, we have overcounted. **Question:** How do I compensate for this?

Comment: You have overcounted.  Two approaches which work better are inclusion-exclusion and Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: The numbers are small here...I'd just enumerate the possible patterns (like $\{1,1,1,1,1,1,4\}$) and populate each of those.  Of course, this method becomes untenable with larger collections.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: $S(10,7)\cdot 7!$, where $S(n,k)$ is the [Strirling number if the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Long answer. Use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). There are $7^{10}$ ways to distribute $10$ customers between $7$ salesmen. We want to subtract the number of distributions where a salesman didn’t get a customer. $\binom71$ ways to choose an empty salesman, and $6^{10}$ ways to distribute the customers between the other salesmen.

Now we have to add the distributions where two salesmen got no customers. There are $\binom72$ of them. And $5^{10}$ ways to distribute the customers.

And so on. In total, we get $$\sum_{k=0}^7 (-1)^k\cdot(7-k)^{10}\cdot\binom7k.$$

The value is equal to $29635200.$

Comment: I see. The Stirling approach is the approach given to me by the book (in the section I'm currently at) but it is only given as the way to solve it and not (yet) proven. The second answer is something I can understand. Thank you! Looking at the Stirling number in my book, I can see where they got it from

Comment: @IdeaFlux Stirling numbers of the second kind is just a notion which has already “incorporated” the inclusion-exclusion principle. Very convenient notion when you get used to it. You just use $S(n,k)$ instead of doing the whole inclusion-exclusion calculation from scratch.

Comment: I'm thinking about how I can apply the inclusion-exclusion principle to my answer (to compensate for the double count) but I can't come up with anything. Is it possible?

Comment: @IdeaFlux I believe, there is a way to continue your reasoning just because the numbers are small. If the numbers are greater, I doubt there is a convenient way to develop your approach.

Answer (score 5):

Since only $3$ patterns are possible, you could use lulu's suggestion to get a third method

*This method would work even if you were allowed to allocate zero tasks to one or more persons.*

$\textbf{[Lay Down Pattern] x [Permute Pattern]}$ to get

$4-1-1-1-1-1-1:\; \dfrac{10!}{4!}\cdot\dfrac{7!}{6!} = 1058400$
$3-2-1-1-1-1-1:\; \dfrac{10!}{3!2!}\cdot\dfrac{7!}{5!} = 12700800$
$2-2-2-1-1-1-1:\; \dfrac{10!}{2!2!2!}\cdot\dfrac{7!}{3!4!} = 15876000$

totalling to $\large{\;\;\boxed{29635200}}$

Comment: This is my numerical answer. I got the idea from partitions (introduced in the section of this exercise) combined with the proof for the $C_R(n,r)$ identity. I still want to learn from my first method so that is why asked specifically for the compensation

Comment: @IdeaFlux: You haven't given a link to your exercise amd proof of identity. However, to prevent overcount, the only other methods I know of are Stirling Numbers of the second kind and inclusion-exclusion which have already been explained in the other answer.

Comment: Ah okay. I am currently going through an old math book so I do not have a link. Since at the time I focused too much on passing my courses I'm now going through it for myself. The answer is therefore not so important whereas reasoning correctly is. I was able to spot the flaw in my reasoning but not the fix. I have still no idea unfortunately but the other answer did help me to think in different ways about the problem which is also helpful. Thank you for your help and effort as well!

Comment: @IdeaFlux: You're welcome !